# Error in download.file : scheme not supported

Tags: r, url, plyr

I need to download some csv files from  "http://www.elections.state.md.us".

And here is my code.

```
url <- "http://www.elections.state.md.us/elections/2012/election_data/index.html"
# recognize the links
links <- getHTMLLinks(url)
filenames <- links[str_detect(links,"_General.csv")]
filenames_list <- as.list(filenames)
filenames
# create a function
downloadcsv <- function(filename,baseurl,folder){
  dir.create(folder,showWarnings = FALSE)
  fileurl <- str_c(baseurl,filename)
  if(!file.exists(str_c(folder,"/",filename))){
    download.file(fileurl,
                  destfile = str_c(folder,"/",filename))
    # 1 sec delay between files
    Sys.sleep(1)
  }
}
library(plyr)
l_ply(filenames_list,downloadcsv,
      baseurl = "www.elections.state.md.us/elections/2012/election_data/",
      folder = "elec12_maryland")
```

The error comes out as :

> Error in download.file(fileurl, destfile = str_c(folder, "/",
>   filename)) :  scheme not supported in URL 'www.elections.state.md.us/elections/2012/election_data/State_Congressional_Districts_2012_General.csv'

However, when I try to paste the url into the IE and it did work. So what is the problem of my code?

Any idea would be helpful,Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the url must start with a scheme such as http://, https://, ftp:// or file://. So in the last line, I changed the code to

```
l_ply(filenames_list,downloadcsv,
      baseurl = "http://www.elections.state.md.us/elections/2012/election_data/",
      folder = "elec12_maryland")
```

And it works.