# Save multiple HDF files from an ftp list in R, giving a different name to each according to the name of the ftp link

Tags: r, url, download, ftp, save

I have a text list of HDF files I need to download from an ftp server.

This is the (example) structure of the list:

```
ftp://username:password@ftppath/File#1_hh_mm_ss.HDF
ftp://username:password@ftppath/File#2_hh_mm_ss.HDF
ftp://username:password@ftppath/File#3_hh_mm_ss.HDF
...
```

I tried to download a single file with this basic script:

```
url = "ftp://username:password@ftppath/File#3_hh_mm_ss.HDF"
       download.file(url, destfile = "Test1.HDF")
```

What I would like to do is to download multiple files at once (i.e., the ones in the list above), and save them automatically, giving at each file the name of the file as it is in the ftp link (i.e., `File#1_hh_mm_ss.HDF, File#2_hh_mm_ss.HDF, File#3_hh_mm_ss.HDF`)

Is anyone able to help?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I noticed that the list of files that I need to download also includes different FTP URLs (i.e.:

```
          'ftp://username1:password1@ftppath/File#1_hh_mm_ss.HDF',
          'ftp://username1:password1@ftppath/File#2_hh_mm_ss.HDF',
          'ftp://username2:password2@ftppath/File#3_hh_mm_ss.HDF',
          'ftp://username2:password2@ftppath/File#4_hh_mm_ss.HDF',
          'ftp://username3:password3@ftppath/File#5_hh_mm_ss.HDF',
          'ftp://username3:password3@ftppath/File#6_hh_mm_ss.HDF',
          ...
```

This makes everything more complicated.

Would it be possible, instead, to download all of the files per each ftp URL?

For example (simplified):

```
ftp://username1:password1@ftppath/File#1, File#2, File#3, File#4, ... .HDF    #(DOWNLOAD ALL .HDF FILES in the ftp folder)
ftp://username2:password2@ftppath/File#1, File#2, File#3, File#4, ... .HDF    #(DOWNLOAD ALL .HDF FILES in the ftp folder )
ftp://username3:password3@ftppath/File#1, File#2, File#3, File#4, ... .HDF    #(DOWNLOAD ALL .HDF FILES in the ftp folder )
...
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use for loop, try this :

```
list_files= list(
"ftp://username:password@ftppath/File#1_hh_mm_ss.HDF",
"ftp://username:password2@ftppath/File#2_hh_mm_ss.HDF",
"ftp://username:password3@ftppath/File#3_hh_mm_ss.HDF",
"...")

for (i in 1:length(list_files))
  {   
   file_name=basename(list_files[[i]])
   #url=paste0(base_url,file_name)
   destfile = paste0("path/to/created_folder/",file_name)
   download.file(list_files[[i]], destfile = destfile)
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to run it, but I get the following error: Error in download.file(url, destfile = file_name) : 
  scheme not supported in URL 'ftp://username:password@ftppath/File#1_hh_mm_ss.HDF' . Please note, I changed "ftp://username:password@ftppath/File#1_hh_mm_ss.HDF" with the actual ftp url.

Comment: it looks that is a problem in the url , try to add `http://` or `https://` to the beginning of your url?. like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763726/error-in-download-file-scheme-not-supported

Comment: That works great! However, I have tried to change the download path but it doesn't work. Can you please help me to download it to a designated folder? I have tried the following: for (i in 1:length(list_files))
  {   
   file_name=basename(list_files[[i]])
   url=paste0(base_url,file_name)
   download.file(url, destfile = "C:/Users/simon/Desktop/FY_3D/file_name")
   }                     What is wrong with this path? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: try with the edited code if it work fine? . you can add `dir.create("directory_name")` if the dir is not yet created!

Comment: Thanks islem, really appreciate your help! This works great, however, I noticed that the list of files that I need to download, includes different FTP URLs. Please, see my last EDIT.

Comment: you are welcome Simone!. in my last update i removed `base_url` to keep the same url in the list of `list_files` so it should work even when basic url is variable. please let me know if still doesn't work